# Running C# Windows Application from CD/USB Drive without installing .NET Framework

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a C# application which needs to run on a client's machine but the client does not want to have to install the .NET framework.  He wants my application to run 'as-is' from a CD or a PenDrive.

How do I make this happen?

Comment: It's not going to happen.  If your application targets a .NET framework, it must exist in order to run.  There is no way around this.

Comment: If you develop and application in .NET, then .NET will need to be installed on the target machines.  Same with a Java app (would need to install the JRE).  However, most Windows machines have .NET 3.5 installed by default or by other applications that most use.  If you do not want to install .NET, you would need to write this in C++ or some similar lower level language.

Answer (score 3):

You need the appropriate version of the .NET framework installed in order to run .NET applications. That's pretty much a requirement.

It's just like trying to run a Java application without the JRE installed, or a PHP application without PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but this is not possible. You need the .NET framework on the machine with the C# code on as the C# code relies on .NET to actually DO anything.